# How to have a Struct with template with a class

Tags: c++, templates, struct

With this code (just a class of test):

```
typedef unsigned short UInt16;

template<class T>
class CClass
{
public:
    SValue* getNewSValue(void);
private:
    typedef struct {
        T *mValue;
        T *next;
        T *previous;
        UInt16 index;
    } SValue;
};

template<typename T>
SValue* CClass<T>::getNewSValue(void)
{
    return new SValue;
}
```

I have the following errors:

> error C2143: syntax error : missing
>   ';' before '*'
>
> error C4430: missing type specifier -
>   int assumed. Note: C++ does not
>   support default-int

Is it possible to use a Struct within a class? If I declare the struct out of the class the template doesn't see the template `T`.

Answer (score 3):

$9.2/2- The key is the below quote from the C++ Standard03

`A class is considered a completely-defined object type (3.9) (or complete type) at the closing } of the class-specifier. Within the class member-specification, the class is regarded as complete within function bodies, default arguments and constructor ctor-initializers (including such things in nested classes). **Otherwise it is regarded as incomplete within its own class member-specification.**

Don't know what is `UINT16`, but the following should work

```
template<class T> 
class CClass 
{ 
private: 
    typedef struct { 
        T *mValue; 
        T *next; 
        T *previous; 
        short int index;                      // Replacing with int for illustration only
    } SValue; 
public:
    SValue* getNewSValue(void); 
private: 
};
```

EDIT 3: The `***` came there trying to make the change BOLD (which I should have deleted anyways)

```
template<class T> typename CClass<T>::SValue* CClass<T>::getNewSValue(void) 
{ 
    return new SValue; 
}

int main(){
    CClass<int> s;
    s.getNewSValue();
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `typename` keywork in the definition of `getNewSValue` ? That's because SValue is unnamed and we have to refer to it using the `typedef` name ?

Comment: @Cedric if we would omit `typename`, it would be parsed like the definition of a member called `SValue` of class `CClass<T>`, for which no type was specified: `tempate<class T> Class<T>::SValue;`. The tokens following would be junk and rejected by the compiler as syntax errors. This all is because the compiler by default assumes non-types if it can't lookup a name at parse time (i.e it doesn't know what `T` is yet, so it can't lookup `SValue`). If you put `typename`, `SValue` is correctly regarded as a typename for the member `getNewSValue`.

Comment: The code you put generates the following error: "error C2244: 'CClass<T>::getNewSValue' : unable to match function definition to an existing declaration"

Comment: for a while you confused me with the triple pointers (\*'s). I think it should be SValue* and not SValue***

Comment: @hype: Yes, it is my fault. I was trying to make it BOLD and then decided not to do it. So I manually removed the leading ** but forgot the trailing ones :(

Have edited my post accordingly

Comment: Can it be achieved by "decltype" now?

Answer (score 1):

Since the member function definition is in global scope, you need to qualify its return type with `CClass::` to refer to the name within class scope. Also, the `typename` keyword is needed when referring to typenames nested within templates.

```
template<typename T>
typename CClass<T>::SValue* CClass<T>::getNewSValue(void)
```

Also, the nested struct is unnamed. Note that in C++, classes and structs have proper names, and a typedef name is not a class name. You will be much better off avoiding the typedef.

```
struct SValue {
    T *mValue;
    T *next;
    T *previous;
    UInt16 index;
};
```

Comment: This is very verbose :-), But Potatos your code generates the following err, on the line: typename CClass<T>::SValue* CClass<T>::getNewSValue(void) ERROR ---> "error C2899: typename cannot be used outside a template declaration"

Comment: @okami: keep the `template< typename T >` part. For less verbose syntax, define the function inside the `class {}` scope. Then `typename` and qualification (on class-local types) aren't needed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `struct` is not defined when you declare the return type of `getNewSValue`.

With that you don't have that error:

```
template<class T>
class CClass
{
public:
    SValue* getNewSValue(void);
private:
    typedef struct {
        T *mValue;
        T *next;
        T *previous;
        UInt16 index;
    } SValue;
};

template<typename T>
SValue* CClass<T>::getNewSValue(void)
{
  return new SValue;
}
```

And you also have to qualify the `SValue` return type, because it is nested in `CClass` when you use it to define `getNewSValue`.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `SValue` before `getNewSValue()`:

```
template<class T> 
class CClass 
{ 
private: 
    typedef struct { 
        T *mValue; 
        T *next; 
        T *previous; 
        UInt16 index; 
    } SValue; 
public: 
    SValue* getNewSValue(void); 
};
```

Also, make sure `UInt16` is defined.

Answer (score 0):

how about trying this ? it worked on VS2008

```
template<class T>
class CClass
{
private:
    typedef struct {
        T *mValue;
        T *next;
        T *previous;
        __int16 index;
    } SValue;

public:
    SValue* getNewSValue(void)
    {
        return new SValue;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The SValue-Type is inside the CClass-namespace. You need to fully qualify the typename outside the class.

```
template<typename T>
CClass<T>::SValue* CClass<T>::getNewSValue(void)
```

Also, you should make SValue public, if it is returned by a public method.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, none of these will compile (on GCC 4.2 at least) as soon as a call to `getNewSValue()` is called. Since it's a public method that returns a pointer to a private type, you'll get a compile error stating that `SValue is private`.

In order for this to work, you'll either need to make SValue public, or change the type of the return value of `getNewSValue()` to something like `void*`, since it seems you're trying to make SValue an opaque type.