# How to use a struct as member in a template class

Tags: c++, class, templates, struct

I am trying to write an adjacency list to save the graph.
And here is my code, the class `Graph` has a member called `Node`. The `Node` can save any type of message, and many children with the cost to them.
After `Node` thers is a `nodes` member to save all of the node in graph.

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Graph {
public:
    struct Node {
        using Ptr = std::shared_ptr<Node>;
        T val;
        std::vector<std::pair<Ptr, int>> children;
        Node() {}
        Node(T data) : val(data) , children() {}
    };

    typename std::vector<Graph<T>::Node::Ptr> nodes;
    Graph(){}
    Graph(size_t n) : nodes(n) {
        for(auto node : nodes)
            node = std::make_shared<Node>();
    }
};
```

**Problem**
`typename std::vector<Graph<T>::Node::Ptr> nodes;`
My compiler doesnot think `Ptr` is a valid type, here is the error

```
type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> class std::vector’
```

I can put the declaration of `Node` out of the `Graph` and make it a template to solve this problem, but why cannot this?

**System Info**

- Ubuntu 20.04 (WSL2)
- g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2) 9.3.0

**Already read**

- [struct of template class in template class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622117/struct-of-template-class-in-template-class)
- https://zh.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name
- [error: name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22922523/error-name-followed-by-must-be-a-class-or-namespace-name)
- [How to have a Struct with template with a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649358/how-to-have-a-struct-with-template-with-a-class)

Comment: `typename` at a wrong place. Try `std::vector<typename Graph<T>::Node::Ptr>`.

Comment: aside: `auto node` is a *copy* of a `Node::Ptr`, and not a *reference*, so all your `Node`s will be destroyed as soon as they are constructed

Comment: aside 2: Why not have `std::vector<Node> nodes` and have non owning pointers in `Node::children`? In either case you will have to clean up pointers to nodes that you remove from your graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use shared_ptr replace the using Ptr = std::shared_ptr;

```
template<typename T>
class Graph {
public:

    struct Node {
        T val;
        std::vector<std::pair<std::shared_ptr<Node>, int>> children;
        Node() {}
        Node(T data) : val(data), children() {}
    };

    typename std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>> nodes;

    Graph() {}
    Graph(size_t n) : nodes(n) {
        for (auto node : nodes)
            node = std::make_shared<Node>();
    }
};
```

or

```
template<typename T>
class Graph {
public:
    struct Node {
        using Ptr = std::shared_ptr<Node>;

        T val;
        std::vector<std::pair<Ptr, int>> children;
        Node() {}
        Node(T data) : val(data), children() {}
    };
    std::vector<typename Graph<T>::Node::Ptr> nodes;
    Graph() {}
    Graph(size_t n) : nodes(n) {
        for (auto node : nodes)
            node = std::make_shared<Node>();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [n-pronouns-m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775806/n-pronouns-m), replace `typename std::vector<Graph<T>::Node::Ptr> nodes;` with `std::vector<typename Graph<T>::Node::Ptr> nodes;`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in `std::vector<Graph<T>::Node::Ptr>`, it is not known that `Graph<T>::Node::Ptr` is a type, so the assumption is that it is a value.

That's the part that needs `typename`, but since it's defined within `Graph<T>`, you don't need all those qualifications:

```
std::vector<typename Node::Ptr> nodes;
```

(Note that `typename std::vector<int> vi;` is valid even though the `typename` is pointless.)